# Create a strong password for AES

Tags: security, encryption, aes, bouncycastle, jasypt

Background: I am using the PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC algorithm ([Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org)) with [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) via the [Grails plugin](https://bitbucket.org/tednaleid/grails-jasypt/wiki/Home). Configuration is straightforward:

```
jasypt {
    algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC"
    providerName = "BC"
    password = "<your very secret passphrase>"
    keyObtentionIterations = 1000
}
```

I would like to know how to choose a secure password for the above. Are there real or practical limits on length, restricted characters, etc? A specific generator I should be using? I couldn't find clear documentation on this and all examples use something like the above (e.g., "password", "secret" etc.).

Comment: If you are using a static key, you should not be using password-based encryption. Instead, just generate a random key and store that directly.

Comment: Thanks, but dumb question, is your suggestion specific to Jasypt? Because I can't find anything in the docs that covers encrypting text without PBE. If I've missed that and there are docs covering your suggestion, can you please point me to them?

Comment: It was a general comment. I'm not familiar with Jasypt, but it seems like it only supports PBE, which is a bit weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Password-based encryption takes a *password*, as the term implies. Passwords are run through a key derivation function to obtain the actual key. As a KDF is typically constructed from a hash function, the password may be of any length and contain any characters.

Passwords have to be run through a KDF because typical passwords don't contain anywhere near enough entropy to be considered secure against brute force attacks. A KDF substitutes this lack of "key space" depth with computationally expensive key derivation – hence the thousands of iterations. The disadvantage is the fact that initializing the cipher is also expensive.

This is a tradeoff well worth it if passwords are required instead of raw keys. However, in your case it would be a better idea to use the raw key. Unfortunately it seems that the Jasypt library you are using only supports PBE.

To contain at least 256 bits of entropy (as much as a raw random 256-bit key), [the password has to contain at least 43 random (case-sensitive) alphanumeric characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Random_passwords). If you pick a password that long, you can probably lower the iteration count to 1.

It seems pretty odd to me that you have to think through all this even though you are using a library that you are supposed to be able to use "without the need of having deep knowledge on how cryptography works". Why does it expose all the ugly details if users aren't supposed to know what they are?

Comment: Thanks, very informative and helpful. It seems Jasypt has some defaults  that probably make it good enough for the encryption ignorant (the basic text encryption uses MD5 and DES and strong uses MD5 and Triple DES, both with 1000 iterations). But they don't make it clear how good this is (or isn't), so I had to laugh at (and agree with) your assessment.

I'll generate the password with KeePass to your specifications.

Comment: DES? Triple-DES? The authors must be total amateurs. DES can be brute forced on a home computer within days, and both DES and Triple-DES are slower than AES. MD5 is also considered broken for cryptographic use. Who knows what other amateur mistakes this library contains – I would stay away from it.

Comment: Thanks again for the background and insight. I think I'd be safe with the above listed Bouncy Castle algorithm/implementation (SHA256 and AES 256, 1000 iterations), no? It's in line with this: http://www.jasypt.org/bouncy-castle.html. To be fair to Jasypt, it seems to be tackling integration (Hibernate, etc.), not encryption (delegates to JCE, Bouncy Castle). But as you recommend, I'll lower the iterations and increase the password to 43 character alphanumeric.

Comment: i have performance issus with 1000 iterations and RandomSaltGenerator.

Answer (score 0):

For generating a secure passphrase, have a look at the [Diceware](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) site.  Note that you have to do the work by hand and **not** use a computer.

Comment: Thanks, but I only care about maximum strength, not memorability.

Comment: To make it stronger, make it longer.  Ten words, (two five word phrases) will give you around 128 bits of security, provided you use real dice and not a PRNG.  The Diceware FAQ is useful here.